# Use object parameters as arguments for function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am sure this has been answered before, but searching only yields results for passing an actual object as a function arguments, however I would like to destructure an object and use its parameters as input arguments for a function.

I am importing the function `foo()` from an external library and would like to supply its arguments using an object containing them. Here is `foo.js` (note that my use case has a lot more input arguments):

```js
export function foo(arg1, arg2) {
  doStuff()
}
```

Here is my code; the following works :

```js
import { foo } from 'foo'

const args = {
  arg1: "value1",
  arg2: "value2",
}

const { arg1, arg2 } = args
foo(arg1, arg2)
```

I would like to be a bit more concise and avoid repeating the variable names `arg1` and `arg2`, along the lines of:

```js
import { foo } from 'foo'

const args = {
  arg1: "value1",
  arg2: "value2",
}

foo(args) // doesn't work, apparently I have to do something more to the args object here
```

But this code doesn't work (`arg1` gets the value of `args` and `arg2` is `undefined`), I assume that this can be achieved, e.g. using the spread operator somehow, but how?

Comment: `function bar({ arg1, arg2 })`, see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Unpacking_fields_from_objects_passed_as_function_parameter)

Comment: you need to get the properties before you call the function unless you change the singature of the function to accept an object for destructuring.

Comment: @ASDFGerte I don't have access to the declaration of foo/bar, I updated the question to reflect this

Comment: Then either use your own suggestion of just calling it by listing the properties as parameters, or write a wrapper, and use that instead (just make a new function `function fooWrapped({ arg1, arg2 }){ return foo.call(this, arg1, arg2); }`)

Answer (score 3):

destructure the object in the function declaration like so:

```
function({arg1 = "", arg2 = 0}) {doStuff()}
```

and remember to always add default values :)

EDIT: what you're doing is impossible basically, because you can't use iterators like this foo(..{arg1, arg2). A solution to this would be unwrapping the object values using Object.values converting them into an array and then destructuring that.

```
function foo(arg1, arg2) {
  console.log(arg1, arg2);
}

function unwrap(object) {
  return Object.values(object);
}

foo(...unwrap({ x: "1", y: "2" }));
```

at this point tho you'd be better off using an array like so:

```
foo(...[1, 2]);
```

Comment: I do not actually have access to the function declaration. Let me update the question to clarify this

Comment: Ah then you have to wrap it, I'll update my answer accordingly :)

Answer (score 0):

You could take a function for unwrapping the *arguments* object and spread the result for calling the wanted function without changing the function's signature.

```js
// given function
function foo(arg1, arg2) {
    console.log(arg1, arg2);
}

const
    unwrap = ({ arg1, arg2 }) => [arg1, arg2], // get all properties in wanted order
    args = { arg1: "value1", arg2: "value2" };

foo(...unwrap(args));
```

Comment: Ok, this looks like it would work but seems similarly or more complex than my first suggestion (destructuring first). I would like to reduce the number of times that I type `arg1`, `arg2` etc. to 1.

Comment: objects have no order. if you are sure about the order, you could take `o => Object.values(o);`

Answer (score 0):

Use `Map` instead object to save insertion order:

```
const args = new Map();

args.set('arg1', 'value1');
args.set('arg2', 'value2');

foo(...args.values());
```